# displaying jInternalFrame from another jinternalFrame over desktop pane in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7, jinternalframe

I want to display jInternalFrame1 over a desktop pane in a jFrame.jInternalFrame1 contains a Button for displaying jInternalFrame2 over the desktop pane by removing jInternalFrame1.

public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

```
a aa=new a();//jInternalFrame1
public main() {
    initComponents();
    jDesktopPane1.add(aa);
    aa.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    }

code under button in jInternalFrame1;

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     b bb=new b();//jInternalFrame2
this.dispose();
   bb.setVisible(true);
}
```

But this code is not displaying the jInternalFrame2.I have seen many solutions for this.But I dont understand how to add these into the desktop pane.sorry for my poor English.
Thank you

Comment: Why code it like this? Whats the point of having two internal frames, if you're just going to make one disappear with the opening of another one. You should just use one internal frame with a `CardLayout`, then you can just switch between the `CardLayout` panels.

Comment: sir actually I tried cardLayout.But I cant add the cards  using navigator (add from palette).For me coding is difficult.So I used drag and drop.Can you tell Why its not possible to add the cards?Yesterday I added.But today cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `bb` to the `jDesktpPane1`. To do that, you need to take a `JDesktopPane` argument as a parameter in your `jInternalFrame1`. Then use that `JDesktopPane` to add the second one.  I put together a simple test run.

Code from `MainFrame`

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    IFrameOne iFrame1 = new IFrameOne(jDesktopPane1);
    jDesktopPane1.add(iFrame1);
    iFrame1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Code from `IFrmaeOne`

```
JDesktopPane desktop;
public IFrameOne(JDesktopPane desktop) {
    initComponents();
    this.desktop = desktop;
}
...
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    IFrameTwo iFrameTwo = new IFrameTwo();
    desktop.add(iFrameTwo);
    this.dispose();
    iFrameTwo.setVisible(true);
}
```

`IFrameTwo` is just an empty `JInternalFrame` class. This works for me. Created with GUI Builder also

---

### UPDATE

> "sir actually I tried cardLayout.But I cant add the cards using navigator (add from palette).For me coding is difficult.So I used drag and drop.Can you tell Why its not possible to add the cards?Yesterday I added.But today cant"

If you want to use a `CardLayout` for the `JInternalFrame` here are the steps

1. You can create `JPanel forms`. So create two of them.
2. In your `JInternalFrame` drag and drop a `JPanel` and extend it to the size of the frame.
3. You need to hand code the `CardLayout` yourself. But it in the constructor

   ```
   public MyInternalFrame() {
       initComponents();
       CardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();
       jPanel1.setLayout(cardLayout);
   }
   ```
4. Then add the two `JPanel` forms you created in step one.

   ```
   jPanel1.add(new PanelForm1(), "panel1");
   jPanel1.add(new PanelForm2(), "panel2");
   ```
5. Then in your `actionPerformed` you can just switch between panels

   ```
   public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.events.ActionEvent e) {
       cardLayout.show(jPanel1, "panel2");
   }
   ```
6. You could switch back and forth if you need to.

Comment: I am going to update my answer with how to use `CardLayout`, look out for it in about 15 minutes

Comment: I want to know whether the cardlayout and (desktop pane & internalframes) are same?meand like replacing cards?which is better?

Comment: please try to use drag and drop code.Otherwise its very difficult to me

Comment: `CardLayout` is so much more cleaner. If you were trying to make the `JInternalFrame` the size of the `MainFrame`, I would get rid of the `JInternalFrame` all together, and just create `JPanel` form files and have the `MainFrame` just hold a blank `JPanel` with the `CardLayout`. You can easily do it with the code above.

Comment: can I use step 5 in any panel?like button in panel3 to display panel7?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many panels as you want to the `CardLayout`. You just need to pass the `CardLayout` to each `JPanel` form like I did with the `JDesktopPane` example. Then you can use the `CardLayout` in that `JPanel` form class to `cardLayout.show(panel3, "panel3");`

Comment: cardlayout.add(new jPanel1(), "panel1");shows cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method add(jPanel1,String)
  location: variable cardlayout of type CardLayout
----

Comment: step4 is written inside step3 right?I wrote like that.It shows error

Comment: Did you create `jPanel1` in a separate `JPanel` form file. The only thing you should do is have an `empty `Jpanel` (`jPanel1`) in your `MainFrame`. The `CardLayout` will hold  the `JPanel` forms you created in different files.

Comment: I created a jFrame.one jPanel placed above the jFrame.at the same time 2 seperate jPanels were creatd and the above codes are placed ' public class f extends javax.swing.JFrame {ardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();
    jPanel1.setLayout(cardlayout);  
    cardlayout.add(new jpanel1, "panel1");}}

Comment: Ok so why would it not be able to find the symbol if it's in the same class file? The CardLayout should be in the `MainFrame`. and set the CardLayout to `jPanel1`. Then add `new OutSidePanel()` to the `CardLayout`

Comment: Do you know how to create a `JPanel` form? You need to create a whole new file. When you're opening a new File, the same place you find `JFrame` form, there should be a `JPanel` form you can select

Comment: yes I tried,if cardlayout.add(new NewJPanel(), "panel1");used it shows  cant find add() or if cardlayout.add(new NewJPanel, "panel1");it shows '(' pr' ] 'expected

Comment: I have written this code below initComponents() in the main frame.sorry if any mistake I made.

Comment: Sorry it should be `jPanel1.add` not `cardLayout.add`. My mistake